# OpenLayers webapplication stopped working in IE11

Tags: crash, internet-explorer-11, openlayers, ie11-developer-tools, web-feature-service

A few years ago we developed an OpenLayers webapplication.
Everything worked fine until a few weeks ago.
The application stopped working in IE11, became very slow in Edge.
No problems with other browsers.
When I try to debug (by pressing F12) IE crashes.
The application is used by a few hundred users, a lot of them use IE.

The application loads a big WFS-file.
During 5 to 10 minutes IE "does not respond".
After that period IE is back and alive, and the application works normally.
This behaviour started a few weeks ago.

I have made a Q&D testaccount and link: http://62.212.154.154/geluidregister/inloggen?u=test123&w=test123
As soon as you load the page IE will hang for a few minutes.
If you press F12 during that period IE will crash.
After those "few minutes" you can use IE normally.
This behaviour started a few weeks ago.
Edge is also 'suffering' but doesn't crash.
Other browsers have no problems.

Settings:

- Internet Explorer: Version 11.674.15063.0 Update version 11.0.47
  (KB4040685)
- Installed KB's since september: 
  KB4051613 
  KB4049179
  KB4041676
  KB4040724 KB4038788 KB4038806
- IE security zone: Protected Mode enabled (translated from Dutch)
- As far as I know there is no Emulation mode (at least I didn't change
  any settings in that area)

Tests/checks:

- Delete cookies and browser history - no results
- Reset IE setting - no results
- Run in 'compatibility mode' - no results
- Test in 'no-Addons mode' - no results
- Event error after IE crashes (only when I press F12):

> ```
> - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
> - <System>
>   <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
>   <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
>   <Level>2</Level> 
>   <Task>100</Task> 
>   <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
>   <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-14T08:20:56.300741300Z" /> 
>   <EventRecordID>20949</EventRecordID> 
>   <Channel>Application</Channel> 
>   <Computer>COMPUTER57</Computer> 
>   <Security /> 
>   </System>
> - <EventData>
>   <Data>IEXPLORE.EXE</Data> 
>   <Data>11.0.15063.608</Data> 
>   <Data>324c3bf4</Data> 
>   <Data>MSHTML.dll</Data> 
>   <Data>11.0.15063.674</Data> 
>   <Data>5d4c0b6f</Data> 
>   <Data>c00000fd</Data> 
>   <Data>004e9e0f</Data> 
>   <Data>37b4</Data> 
>   <Data>01d35d210863f55d</Data> 
>   <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE</Data> 
>   <Data>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSHTML.dll</Data> 
>   <Data>61f7af7b-f2fc-43e6-98d5-7ee291007ec8</Data> 
>   <Data /> 
>   <Data /> 
>   </EventData>
>   </Event>
> ```

Debugging:

I've tried the following (thanks to IECustomizer Rob):

- Open blank page
- Apply setting

  "Always record developer console messages"
- Press F12 and apply settings:

  "Network recording ON"

  "Break on ALL exceptions"
- Go to problem website with the dev tool open

But still IE crashes.

Could it be a recent IE/Edge update that's creating this problem?.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Koen